# Implicit data type conversion `DATE` to `NUMBER`

Tags: sql, oracle11g

The query that gives error is

```
 SELECT hire_date+sysdate from Employees;
```

Why oracle does not do implicit `DATE` to `NUMBER` conversion during  `hire_date+sysdate` as it does during `hire_date-sysdate` . Is it because `hire_date+sysdate` it does not make sense? or anything else.

Edit:-

Now I got the answer, thanks to all.

Comment: what is your desired output ?

Comment: What does it mean to you to add two dates?  That doesn't generally make sense.  What does March 1, 2012 + April 17, 1842 even mean?

Comment: There is no implicit "data type conversion" going on when you _subtract_ one date from another like e.g.: `hire_date - sysdate`. That simply calculates the number of days between the two dates. No date is converted to anything. But _adding_ two dates doesn't make sense (as Justin already commented)  - same as multiplying two dates doesn't make sense. Of divide one by another.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name   But as we know operator `-` takes only `Numeric` data type as parameters and oracle implicit data conversion rule is _"When you use a SQL function or operator with an argument of a datatype other than the one it accepts, Oracle converts the argument to the accepted datatype"_ .  Then how come `date` not converted to `number` during `-`

Comment: No. The operator `-` **is** defined for DATEs and TIMESTAMPs. And  `+` is defined for the combination of DATEs/TIMESTAMP and INTERVALs. And when used with those, Oracle does **not** convert the values to numbers. See the manual for details: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#g196492

Answer (score 0):

Actually id doesnt make sense.

But the query is :

```
add_months(hire_date,extract(year from sysdate)*12+ extract(month from sysdate)) +extract(day from sysdate)
```